# Get Keys from dynamic json string in c#

Tags: arrays, asp.net, json

I have a variable json string which looks something like this

```
[{"UserId":1,"PlatformName":"A","Value_Number1":11,"Value_Number2":12}, 
 {"UserId":2,"PlatformName":"B","Value_Number1":13,"Value_Number2":14}]
```

raw output string

```
"[{\"UserId\":1,\"PlatformName\":\"A\",\"Value_Number1\":11,\"Value_Number2\":12}, 
  {\"UserId\":2,\"PlatformName\":\"B\",\"Value_Number1\":13,\"Value_Number2\":14}]"
```

I need to extract key names from this json string.

```
i.e userid,platfromName,Value_Number1,Value_number2
```

This needs to be dynamic as there will be more keys like `Value_Number3,ValueNumber4` in some cases but the format will be similar.

I looked upon examples but couldn't really relate to my scenario .

How can achieve this when number of keys and its names is not known to me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make it in one line using Newtonsoft.Json

```
IEnumerable names = JArray.Parse(jsonString)
             .SelectMany(x => ((JObject) x).Properties().Select(x =>x.Name ));
```

Answer (score 0):

### System.Text.Json

```
var json = "[{\"UserId\":1,\"PlatformName\":\"A\",\"Value_Number1\":11,\"Value_Number2\":12},{\"UserId\":2,\"PlatformName\":\"B\",\"Value_Number1\":13,\"Value_Number2\":14}]";

using var document = JsonDocument.Parse(json);
HashSet<string> properties = document.RootElement
    .EnumerateArray()
    .SelectMany(item => item.EnumerateObject(), (_,prop) => prop.Name)
    .ToHashSet();
```

Result:

```
UserId
PlatformName
Value_Number1
Value_Number2
```